# Suitable piece of hardware for writing first driver?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I want to write a driver for an actual piece of hardware but I don't know what would be a good choice.

I would really like to write drivers for a webcam. Now I realize that I will need some sort of low level specification from the manufacturer, but I do not know which manufacturers distribute those documents?